# How to incorporate password along with passwordless login in ansible dynamic inventory

Tags: authentication, dynamic, ansible, ansible-inventory

I give the end user to either provide username i.e `dest_user` for which ssh-keys is already setup on Linux for all destination hosts i.e `dest_host`.

Below is how I setup dynamic inventory for passwordless user

```yaml
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: dest_nodes
    ansible_user: "{{ dest_user }}"
  with_items: "{{ dest_host.split() }}"
  when: dest_user != ""
```

All good. The second scenario is when the user does not provide any `dest_user` then his SSO username (I get this from their Jenkins login) and password i.e., `dest_pass` which he enters manually should be used for all hosts in the dynamic inventory.

How can I construct `dest_nodes` group to accommodate both username for passwordless login and both username-password for SSO login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally prompt for a variable using the [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) module, and use the special variable [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) to make the `ansible_password` optional in your `add_host` task.

*Note: as you seems to have a pretty good idea on the way to get the user from Jenkins, I assumed it in a variable `dest_user_from_jenkins`, here.*

Here would be the two tasks to do so:

```yaml
- pause:
    prompt: Please enter your password
    echo: no
  register: dest_pass
  when: dest_user | default('') == ''

- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: dest_nodes
    ansible_user: "{{ dest_user | default(dest_user_from_jenkins) }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ dest_pass.user_input | default(omit) }}"
  loop: "{{ dest_host.split() }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    dest_host: foo bar
    dest_user_from_jenkins: dest_user_not_set

  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: Please enter your password
        echo: no
      register: dest_pass
      when: dest_user | default('') == ''

    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: dest_nodes
        ansible_user: "{{ dest_user | default(dest_user_from_jenkins) }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ dest_pass.user_input | default(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ dest_host.split() }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          user: {{ hostvars[item].ansible_user }}
          password: {{ 
            hostvars[item].ansible_password 
              | default('password has not been set!') 
          }}
      loop: "{{ groups['dest_nodes'] }}"
```

We end up having two possible paths:

- When run without any extra parameter, this yields:

  ```
  TASK [pause] ***********************************************************
  [pause]
  Please enter your password (output is hidden):
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [add_host] ********************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=foo)
  ok: [localhost] => (item=bar)

  TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=foo) => 
    msg: |-
      user: dest_user_not_set
      password: password
  ok: [localhost] => (item=bar) => 
    msg: |-
      user: dest_user_not_set
      password: password
  ```
- When run with `--extra-vars "dest_user=dest_user_set"`, this yields:

  ```
  TASK [pause] ***********************************************************
  skipping: [localhost]

  TASK [add_host] ********************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=foo)
  ok: [localhost] => (item=bar)

  TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=foo) => 
    msg: |-
      user: dest_user_set
      password: password has not been set!
  ok: [localhost] => (item=bar) => 
    msg: |-
      user: dest_user_set
      password: password has not been set!
  ```